# Re Exporting everything is not working as expected - issue while import in another file

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am writing the custom render for test files in react project which is using react testing library so that i can avoid the boiler plate for every test file where i have wrapped it with the  Tag.

So in the custom render file test-util.tsx I am exporting everything from @testing-library/react so that I can import my custom render function and all the other React Testing Library functionality (fireEvent , screen etc.) from the same place.

but while doing so i can not import other RTL functions like fireEvent, screen, waitFor etc.

Below is my code :

**test-utils.tsx:**

```
import React, {FC, ReactElement} from 'react';
import {render} from '@testing-library/react';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';

const mockStore = configureStore([]);

const customRender = (
  ui: ReactElement,
  {initialState = {}, store = mockStore(initialState), ...renderOptions} = {}
) => {
  const ProviderWrapper: FC = ({children}) => {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>
      </Router>
    );
  };

  return render(ui, {wrapper: ProviderWrapper, ...renderOptions});
};

export * from '@testing-library/react';

export {customRender as renderWithProviders};
```

**test file** -- abc.test.tsx

```
import {renderWithProviders, screen, fireEvent, waitFor} from 'test-utils';
```

errors :

has no exported member 'fireEvent'

has no exported member 'waitFor'

to avoid the relative import i have done below config set up:

**jest.config.json :**

test-utils is under src/utils/test-utils

```
module.exports = {
   ...
   moduleDirectories: ['src', 'node_modules', '<rootDir>/src/utils'],
   ...
}
```

**tsconfig.json: **

```
  "compilerOptions" : {
   ...,
  "baseUrl": "./src",
  "paths": {
      "^/*": ["../*"],
      "@/*": ["*"],
      "test-utils": ["./utils/test-utils"]
    }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Your file is named `test-utils` but you're referencing it as `testUtils` in `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: sorry that a typo error while posting the issue here, it is still doesnt work with test-utils all places @juliomalves